# React - ComponentDidMount not getting value from Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am getting the Redux state updated correctly. Here is what the Redux state of `updateNeeded` is (In this case it is true).
[image]

I am console logging the value `this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded` but it is always the initial state that I set. It is not getting updated from the Redux State. Below is the code where I make the api call.

```
class CompleteProfile extends Component {
  state = {
    completeProfile: false,
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    let { dispatch, session } = this.props
    dispatch(getMandatoryFields(session.username))
    console.log(
      'this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded -- ' +
        this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded
    )
    if (this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded !== false) {
      this.setState({
        completeProfile: this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded,
      })
    }
  }
...
...
....
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  mandatory_fields: state.User.mandatory_fields,
  session: state.User.session,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CompleteProfile)
```

The console log result is

```
this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded -- false
```

It should be `true` as shown in the Redux state image above. What am I missing ?

Comment: I can't stand seeing mixed formats for your variable name. Better use camel case, not underscore-separated, for your object keys. Also, capitalized case is for classes only, so `User` should be just `user`.

Comment: Point taken. I renamed the variable. Thanks

Comment: Everytime you update redux state it will match the current state with updated state and then re-render the whole component. If you want to access updated state immediately then you need to use store.getState() and access your object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must check `this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded` in `componentDidUpdate` hook. After you change Redux state, the Component will be updated. So you must check `props` in `componentDidUpdate` instead of right after you call dispatch. You can see my code:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    console.log(
        'this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded -- ' +
        this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded
    )
}
```

Your code will become:

```
class CompleteProfile extends Component {
  state = {
    completeProfile: false,
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let { dispatch, session } = this.props
    dispatch(getMandatoryFields(session.username))
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(
      'this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded -- ' +
        this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded
    )
    if (this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded !== false) {
      this.setState({
        completeProfile: this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded,
      })
    }
  }
...
...
....
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  mandatory_fields: state.User.mandatory_fields,
  session: state.User.session,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CompleteProfile)
```

Comment: Thanks. What are `prevProps, prevState, snapshot` ?

Comment: also, add conditional statements comparing prevProps and current props to prevent infinite loop since OP used `setState` inside it.

Comment: You can see detail at here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate :) And you should learn more about lifecycle in React Component.

Comment: I did try componentDidUpdate but it was not firing at all. My console,log never showed up. Also the goal of this code is to show a popup to a user to complete his profile as soon as the home page of the App loads. So if `updateNeeded` is true in Redux state, I have to fire the popup.

Comment: Works fine.I get the concept too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With @Max's solution, your whole new code should be like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  let { dispatch, session } = this.props
  dispatch(getMandatoryFields(session.username))
  console.log(
    'this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded -- ' +
      this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded
  );
  if (!prevProps.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded && this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded) {
    this.setState({
      completeProfile: this.props.mandatory_fields.updateNeeded,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried this before asking the question. componentDidUpdate was not firing at all. Also the goal of this code is to show a popup to a user to complete his profile as soon as the home page of the App loads. So if updateNeeded is true in Redux state, I have to fire the popup. There will not be a change in state because on load, if `updateNeeded` is true, I have to use it to fire the popup.

Comment: All set - I also used the code to avoid loop. Thanks