# Accessing redux state in ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm facing an issue with Redux and React

I use a redux action to fetch data from an API. When the component mounts, this action is fired and populate the Redux state. I want a second action to be fired with parameters (`article`) from the redux state.

My issue is that when I fire the second action, the redux state is still empty, so `article` is null, which causes an error.

```
componentDidMount() {

  const { targetArticle, userVisit, match, article } = this.props

  targetArticle(match.params.slug); 

  userVisit(match.params.slug, article.title);

}
```

I've already checked other topics on the subject like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142493/react-componentdidmount-not-getting-value-from-redux-state), but none of them works for me. How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: What are the actions you are dispatching doing? If ```userVisit``` depends on data that is updated in the state by ```targetArticle```, the data will not be present because ```componentDidMount``` runs before any updates occur.  It's hard to say what a potential solution might be without seeing the side effects your actions are causing.

Comment: You're probably going to have to hook into `componentDidUpdate` since that would be the next lifecycle method you'd have access to after your `componentDidMount` method finishes. But, you'll have to check for changes before using it as you can fall into an infinite loop.

Comment: You guessed right, `targetArticle` fetches data and update redux store, then `userVisit` use a store object property as a parameter

Answer (score 5):

You'd probably have to use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. So given that `userVisit` is dependent on the result of `targetArticle`  and assuming you are looking to this.props. for the updated Redux state, something like this should get you there:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.article !== this.props.article) {
    // Now you have access to targetArticle's result and updated Redux state
    userVisit(match.params.slug, this.props.article.title)
  }
}
```

More in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate